# Fishing Game Code ActionScript 2.0 to ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to make a fishing game where each fish you catch gives you a point and different enemies subtract points. I have found a tutorial for this in ActionScript 2 but I can't find any for action script 3 (here is the link to what I want to replicate: http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Games/Creating-Imtiazur-1297/index.php). I am relatively new at action script as I have only made animations before but I was able to do a little but then couldn't figure out the rest.

I currently have the fishing line moving up and down and does not go beyond the fishing line but I'm not sure how to make the line get longer when it goes down. At the moment the whole line and hook move with a space between it and the rod. I also have to click before the line moves (I'm not sure how to make it instantly usable when going to the frame). I also have one fish moving across the screen. I don't know how to make multiple of the same fish or enemies going across the screen at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated​!

```
fish.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_AnimateHorizontally);

function fl_AnimateHorizontally(event:Event)

{ 
    fish.x = fish.x + 5; if (fish.x>1100) 
    { 
        fish.x = -100; 
    } 

    shark.x = shark.x + 7; if (shark.x>3500) 
    { 
        shark.x = -400; 
    } 

    jellyfish.x = jellyfish.x + 3; if (jellyfish.x>3000) 
    { 
        jellyfish.x = -100; 
    }

    boot.x = boot.x + 5; if (boot.x>1500) 
    { 
        boot.x = -100; 
    } 

    barrel.x = barrel.x + 4; if (barrel.x>1600) 
    { 
        barrel.x = -100; 
    } 
}

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

rope.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        rope.y -= 10; hook.y -= 10;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        rope.y += 10; hook.y += 10;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        rope.x -= 0; hook.x -= 0;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        rope.x += 0; hook.x += 0;
    }
    if (rope.y < 35)
    {
        rope.y = 35; hook.y = 100;
    }

}



function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I was able to do a little but then couldn't figure out the rest"_ Not clear where you are stuck... Are you getting errors? Is there a code line that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I have done a little bit but it was just moving the line up and down using code snippets. For the line, I used Move with Arrow keys and for the fish, I used Move horizontally.

Comment: I haven't done much ActionScript 3 before so I don't know exactly what I am doing. This is for an animation assignment so I can't change the premise, unfortunately.

Comment: Use [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56695815/edit) to show the code that moves up/down/horiz and requires click to move. It'll be easier to advise how to fix. Also.. Do you have an `enterFrame` function anywhere (to animate objects)? In AS3 you don't put code on MClips like `onClipEvent`, also no need for `_root.` before variables like `_root.score` etc... PS: Please don't ask for free code conversions. It's against site rules. The idea is you learn from the answer(s) and they also help other visitors with same issue in future.

Comment: So sorry! I updated the question to be more specific!